# Random walk on 10x10 Array

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array

i am having a problem figuring out an algorithm for this problem,been trying for few days without success,here is a pic of what im trying to obtain:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X70nX.png

Here is my code tried many differents solutions but always get stuck at the same point:(Sorry for mixed language the important part is in english)

ps
im not supposed to use functions to solve this problem only loops and array.

**EDIT 
after much fixing it does the walk but seldomly crashes
any idea?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){

char box[10][10];
int i,j;
int move,row,col;
char letter='A';
srand(time(NULL)); 

printf("\n\tSTART\n\n");

for(i=0;i < 10 ;i++)/* righe */
{
 for(j=0;j < 10;j++) /* colonne */
 {
  box[i][j] = '.'; /* assegno . a tutti gli elementi dell array */
  if(j == 9)
   printf("%c%c\n", box[i][j]); /* giustifico ogni 10 elementi dell array j(0-9) */
   else 
   printf("%c%c", box[i][j]);
  }
}


/* LETS START */ 

printf("\n\n    Inizia il gioco\n\n");

/* random place to start */

row = rand() % 9;
col = rand() % 9;
box[row][col]= 'A';


while(letter <= 'Z')
{
 if(box[row+1][col] == '.' || box[row-1][col] == '.' || box[row][col+1] == '.' || box[row][col-1] == '.' )
 {
 move=rand() % 4;
 switch(move){
              case 0: /* Going UP */
                    if((row != 0) && (box[row-1][col] == '.'))
                    {
                            box[row-1][col]=++letter;
                            box[row--][col];
                    }else{
                          move=rand() % 4;
                          }
              case 1:/* Going Down */
                   if((row != 9) && (box[row+1][col] == '.'))
                   {
                           box[row+1][col]=++letter;
                           box[row++][col];
                   }else{
                         move=rand() % 4;
                         }
              case 2: /*Going Left */
                   if((col != 0) && (box[row][col-1] == '.'))
                   {
                           box[row][col-1]=++letter;
                           box[row][col--];
                   }else{
                         move=rand() % 4;
                         }
              case 3: /* Going Right */
                   if((col != 9) && (box[row][col+1] == '.') )
                   {
                           box[row][col+1]=++letter;
                           box[row][col++];
                   }else{
                         move=rand() % 4;
                         }
              }
 }else{
        printf("\n\nBloccato a %c\n\n", letter);
        break;
 }
}


 /* FINE */

for(i=0;i<10;i++)/* righe */
{
 for(j=0;j<10;j++) /* colonne */
 {
   if(j == 9)
     printf("%c%c\n", box[i][j]); /* giustifico ogni 10 elementi dell array j(0-9) */
    else 
     printf("%c%c", box[i][j]);
 }  
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does it get stuck? What kinds of output are you seeing?

Comment: didnt know there were one :) sorry and for those who cares is not an assignement just testing my very low problem solving ability :)

Comment: i get something like this
http://imgur.com/39TP5
my walker doesnt walk :/

Comment: Your tests (in the ifs) with `=` are wrong. The comparison is done with `==`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to update `row` and `col` inside the loop.
Otherwise you'll always attempt to walk from the position of the 'A'.

... and once all 4 directions are filled, you're stuck in a infinite loop

```
. . . . .
. . B . .
. E A C .
. . D . .
```

---

Even when you update `row` and `col` inside the loop (and correct the `==` mistake), you have to handle a problem: suppose the first spot (the 'A') is the top left corner and the next random directions are East, South, South, West, and North. ... now what? :)

```
A B .
F C .
E D .
. . .
```

Comment: the loop terminates fine, but if the first space a letter is supposed to go isn't available, the letter won't be used.

Comment: The loop terminates because your tests are wrong: `if (box[row][col] == '.') ...` Note `==`, not `=`

Comment: How did i miss the == i read it so many times that it looked normal,shame on me.
also im trying to figure out how to update row and col inside the loop but i have no idea on where to look

Comment: @pmg 
it should terminate but im trying to figure out how to write this :D
absolutely no experience on me im going crazy on this problem

Comment: Something like `box[row][++col]=letter;` ?

Comment: @kdma: one suggestion for you. Solve the termination problem first. Simplify it to: *if the random direction can't be taken stop the walk*. Sometimes you'll get a short walk, but that's ok for now.

Comment: So added
 `for(letter = 'B'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
    {
     if(box[row+1][col] == '.' || box[row-1][col] == '.' || box[row][col+1] == '.' || box[row][col-1] == '.' )`
to solve locked direction problems 

@steabert
i dont understand how should i use that line

BTW thanks everyone for the help i didnt know stackoverflow was so awesome

Comment: @kdma: well, it was mentioned here that you should update the position.  This can be done by using `++row` or `++col`, which first increases the `row` or `col` variable and then uses it.

Comment: i believe im close to the solution but still missing something in the big picture:
the "walker" now walks but the letters are repeated in a strange way,trying to figure out what is wrong :)

Comment: Imagine you get a move `0` first and then a move `1`. What happens? You go into the case and see that `row != 9` so you set the `box[row+1][col]` to `'C'` ... ok ... but **what was in the place now occupied with the `C` before?**

Comment: i believe that the letters get written over other letters but how do i check if a letter is already present in that `bow[row][col]` and how do i change direction in that case?
i think i have to write this algorithm again :D

Comment: [hehehe](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RewriteCodeFromScratch) -- Every time you rewrite the code from scratch, you put into the new version things you learned before. So, go ahead: delete your current version and restart --- Oh! you may think about investing some time in learning how to use a version control system.

Comment: thanks i will look into it,now its time for some rest i will try to complete this by tomorrow i ll update this as soon as it done :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to "reroll" the random number when you discover that you cannot go in some direction, because if you have bad luck, you get the same number twice (or even 3 or 4 or more times) - so even if you generated 4 random numbers and they all failed, that doesn't mean that you're stuck.

You can solve this problem by generating one number, and trying all 4 possible directions starting from it:

> If the random number generator returned 0: check 0, 1, 2, 3
>
> If the random number generator returned 1: check 1, 2, 3, 0
>
> If the random number generator returned 2: check 2, 3, 0, 1
>
> If the random number generator returned 3: check 3, 0, 1, 2

Implemented by the following code:

```
desired_move = rand();
success = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4 && !success; ++i)
{
    move = (desired_move + i) % 4;
    switch (move)
    {
    case 0: // Go up
        if (row > 0 && box[row - 1][col] == '.')
        {
            row = row - 1;
            success = 1;
        }
        break;
    case 1: // Go down
        ...
    }
}
if (!success) // Tried all 4 directions but failed! You are stuck!
{
    goto START_OVER; // or whatever else
}
```

Note that this algorithm is not very random: if you cannot go up, there is a greater chance that you go down than right or left. If you want to fix it, you can pick a random permutation of 4 directions instead of checking the directions sequentially:

```
const int permutation_table[24][4] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {0, 1, 3, 2},
    {0, 2, 1, 3},
    ...
    {3, 2, 1, 0}
};
index = rand() % 24;
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    move = permutation_table[index][i];
    switch (move) {
    ... // As above
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I will try to implement this kind of solution when i start over :) and try to finish it by tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

When you're in for loop.

1. Draw a possible direction

```
int direction = rand()%4;
```

1. Check all possible directions if the drawed one is invalid (not in array or not a ".")

```
int i=-1;
while( ++i < 4 )
{
    switch(direction) 
    {
        case 0:
            if( row-1 >= 0 && box[row-1][col] == '.' ) {
                --row;
                i = -1;    
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if( col+1 < 10 && box[row][col+1] == '.' ) {
                ++col;
                i = -1;    
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if( row+1 < 10 && box[row+1][col] == '.' ) {
                ++row;
                i = -1;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if( col-1 >= 0 && box[row][col-1] == '.' ) {
                --col;
                i = -1;
            }
            break;
    }

    if( i != -1 ) {
        direction = (direction+1)%4;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

1. If there's no valid move end the for loop>

```
if( i == 4 ) {
    break;
}
```

1. Otherwise write a letter to the table cell and update row/col position.

```
box[row][col] = letter;
```

And... that's all I guess. This is greedy algorithm so you don't need any optimizations (at least I don't see any in exercise requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the help updated the code with a similar approach but as i writed above the algorithm works fine now but seldomly crashes and when it does it doesnt start the walk any guess?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Program doesn't end, give false return or have a memory error (e.g. segmentation fault?)

Comment: The program runs until the "walk" algorithm and then stops waiting for input with a blinking "_" dont know what kind of error it means, very newb here :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are breaking out of your switch statement if you try to go in a direction that isn't valid, but you increment your counter anyway.  Try to check another random direction if that happens.

Comment: ok added another `move=rand() % 4;` inside the Else but still looking for a condition that checks wheter the sourrounding elements are taken or not

Comment: remove the `else{ move=rand() % 4; }` blocks and `break;` each case. Check [this link](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/SYNTAX/switch.html) for example on "falling-through cases"

Answer (score 0):

where exactly does it break?

from what I can see at a glance is that you have a chance that It_that_walks gets in position from witch it cant go anywhere:

```
A B C D .
. I J E .
. H G F .
```

where after J?

There is no need for the `&& (box[row][col-1]= '.')`

Allso, it is wrong (assignment instead of comparison), it should be: `&& (box[row][col-1]== '.')` (but you dont need it alltogether)

Comment: Okay deleted the `&& (box[row][col-1]== '.')` since it wasnt necessary but i cant figure out how to check if the sourrounding elements are taken