# A random walk across 10x10?

Tags: c, arrays

This the problem i am trying to solve  in C:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X70nX.png

I have wrote this code but i don't know what is wrong . It doesn't give me any output, just an empty screen ![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnxtA.jpg)

That is my Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define ROW 10 
#define COL 10

#define RIGHT 0
#define UP  1
#define LEFT 2 
#define DOWN 3

int main(void)
{
    char mat[ROW][COL];
    bool try;
    int move, co, ro,letter;

//Filling the grid with "."
    for (ro = 0; ro < ROW; ro++)
    {
        for (co = 0; co < COL; co++)
            mat[ro][co] = '.';
    }

//Initial Values
    co = 0; ro = 0; mat[0][0] = 'A';


    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (letter = 1; letter < 26; letter++)
    {
        try = true;

        while (try)
        {
            move = rand() % 4;

            if ((move == RIGHT) && (co + 1 < COL) && (mat[ro][co+1]=='.'))
            {
                mat[ro][co + 1] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                co++; try=false;
            }

            if ((move == UP) && (ro - 1 >= 0) && (mat[ro-1][co]=='.') )
            {
                mat[ro - 1][co] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                ro--; try = false;
            }

            if ((move == LEFT) && (co - 1 >= 0) && (mat[ro][co-1]=='.'))
            {
                mat[ro][co - 1] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                co--; try = false;
            }

            if ((move == DOWN) && (ro + 1 < ROW) && (mat[ro+1][co]=='.'))
            {
                mat[ro + 1][co] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                ro++;
            }
        }
    }


//Printing The GRID
    for (ro = 0; ro < ROW; ro++)
    {
        for (co = 0; co < COL; co++)
            printf(" %c", mat[ro][co]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now there is a similar discussion about the same problem here : [Random walk on 10x10 Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542267/random-walk-on-10x10-array)

but I still don't know what is the problem with my code !!... please consider me as a beginner .

Revising : 
This is the new one after taking the comments into consideration :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define ROW 10 
#define COL 10

#define RIGHT 0
#define UP  1
#define LEFT 2 
#define DOWN 3

int main(void)
{
    char mat[ROW][COL];
    bool try;
    int move, co, ro,letter,blocked;

//Filling the grid with "."
    for (ro = 0; ro < ROW; ro++)
    {
        for (co = 0; co < COL; co++)
            mat[ro][co] = '.';
    }

//Initial Values
    co = 0; ro = 0; mat[0][0] = 'A';


    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (letter = 1; letter < 26; letter++)
    {
        try = true;
        blocked = 0;
        while (try)
        {
            move = rand() % 4;
            switch (move)
            {

            case RIGHT:
            {   if ((co + 1 < COL) && (mat[ro][co + 1] == '.'))
            {
                mat[ro][co + 1] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                co++; try = false; break;
            }
            else { blocked++; break; }}

            case UP:
            {   if ((move == UP) && (ro - 1 >= 0) && (mat[ro - 1][co] == '.'))
            {
                mat[ro - 1][co] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                ro--; try = false; break;
            }
            else { blocked++; break; }}

            case LEFT:
            {   if ((move == LEFT) && (co - 1 >= 0) && (mat[ro][co - 1] == '.'))
            {
                mat[ro][co - 1] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                co--; try = false; break;
            }
            else { blocked++; break; }}

            case DOWN:
            {if ((move == DOWN) && (ro + 1 < ROW) && (mat[ro + 1][co] == '.'))
            {
                mat[ro + 1][co] = mat[ro][co] + 1;
                ro++; try = false; break;
            }
            else { blocked++; break; }}
            }
            if (blocked == 4)
            {try = false; letter=26;}
        }  

    }


//Printing The GRID
    for (ro = 0; ro < ROW; ro++)
    {
        for (co = 0; co < COL; co++)
            printf(" %c", mat[ro][co]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the code work only sometimes but it doesn't stop after 'Z' (it supposed to be letter=26) ,

Comment: I don't know c (I know Java), but don't you have to close the curly brackets at the end? The `for` bracket and the `int main` bracket?

Comment: One bug is that the code does not set `try = false` after taking a step DOWN. As a result, it will not ever think it has taken a step down and will always take an extra step after that. That's not the cause of your problem here -- walking yourself into a corner is -- but the extra steps are almost surely making the problem worse. [Originally given as an answer, but moved here because it is not a good answer]

Comment: you are right about (try=false) .. i will consider the corner thing

Comment: I don't think you can get a boolean with the name try, likewise with the name if or while

Comment: The test `blocked == 4` is incorrect. It may happen that you choose the same direction several times (imagine generating L,L,L,L), then you will end the walk even though you can continue. You should instead add a test at the beginning which looks at all neighboring cells and continue if there is at least one dot available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code works **sometimes**. I think you often get into an infinite loop because you generate a random walk which is impossible to continue. Like this:

```
A B C .
H I D .
G F E .
. . . .
```